# Qt non-GUI program not starting at Windows 11 system startup

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I've written a program in Qt 6.4 for Windows. I'm running Windows 11. The program is a non-GUI program (no QWidgets etc.). It spawns threads to countdown and after countdown it plays an audio file. The program produces log in a file named `log.txt` and save the log in the working folder (where the .exe file is).

Here's the `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    const QStringList uiLanguages = QLocale::system().uiLanguages();
    for (const QString &locale : uiLanguages) {
        const QString baseName = "PeriodicSoundMaker_" + QLocale(locale).name();
        if (translator.load(":/i18n/" + baseName)) {
            a.installTranslator(&translator);
            break;
        }
    }
    AudioManager();

    return a.exec();
}
```

When I double click the .exe file, I can see it running in the task manager. I can see it produces log and plays the audio file after countdown as expected.

I want to run this program at Windows startup, before any user log in, at the log in screen. I utilized Task Scheduler to create a Task, that'd start the program at Windows startup.

To test, I restart Windows and wait at the log in screen. No audio file played after the countdown.

Then I log into Windows, open Task Manager and found that the .exe file is running. I also checked the same from Task Scheduler and found that the task is running. However, I don't see any log produced in the `log.txt` file. There will always be some logs if the program starts.

What's the reason behind this different behaviours? What can I do to run the program at Windows system startup?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When specifying `Action`, the `Start in (optional)` must be the folder where the .exe file resides. There can't be any double quotation (") surrounding the folder path, even if there are spaces in the path.

For example, if the program is at `E:\My Programs\A B C\a.exe`, then `Start in (optional)` should be `E:\My Programs\A B C\`, without any quotes.